# resource not publishing automatically when change in Spring 3 + eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, spring-mvc

Previously i worked with Spring 2.5.6, and whenever i do some changes in jsp pages, i simply refresh the project in eclipse and the change will be reflect.

But then, we are migrating this to 3.0 and everything is fine, but even when i make some changes in JSP, and refresh the project, it is not reflecting. Every time we need to restart the server, to see the changes.

I tried everywhere and didn't get a solution for this.

I am using Eclipse 3.3 + jdk 1.6.0_22 + Windows 7. I am suffering a lot because of this and it would be great if someone helps me fix this issue

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes this can be due to your browser caching, especially "big" files like javascript or css.  Couple things to try might be clearing your cache manually, or getting a browser like Firefox or Chrome, using the private browsing feature (nothing is cached in private browsing) and using that to test new features. (This is especially true if you're using the new `<resources>` bean in Spring MVC, which I believe automatically caches resources it's pointed at)

If this does not work, your container could be set to not republish on application changes.

Comment: I changed my context.xml not to republish, and voila it is working now. Thanks @dardo. Sometime such small thing left un-noticed make your life miserable